# Slow logback start up times

Tags: java, logback

In a very simple Java application, with logback using default values (no `logback.xml` in `src/main/resources`), the application starts up in around 400ms.  As soon as we add a basic `logback.xml` to the classpath (`src/main/resources`), the start up time increases to around 5500ms.  We have seen this in multiple projects.  The config is as follows:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-7level - %-50logger{36} - %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.sql2o" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: what is the most verbose part of your code according to your console?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto - During start up there is literally only 6 INFO printouts.  This is a standard Spark Java, Hello World application.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using logback 1.1.7 / slf4j 1.7.21 on jdk 1.8.0_91. Without `logback.xml` I get 75ms run time, and with `logback.xml` I get 160ms run time, when logging 10 info messages. Test code: `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class); for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) logger.info("Hello world " + i);` BTW: That is what is called an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Andreas - using the the same as you, without logback.xml (`17:44:24.380 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @417ms`) and with logback.xml (`17:45:36.298 INFO    - org.eclipse.jetty.util.log                         - Logging initialized @5524ms`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

5 seconds looks like a dns query timeout. It was the case for me. Just be sure that the hostname of your computer resolve to an ip. You can test that doing a ping:

```
ping `hostname`
```

If it resolve the name and start pinging, your problem is something else. But if you see a message saying "bad address", this may explain your problem.

To fix it simply, you can just add your hostname to the `/etc/hosts` file. Just add the hostname at the end of the line starting with 127.0.0.1.
The change should apply immediately. It may not be the cleanest way to fix that, especially on modern linux with dhcp and so on. But if it works, you'll have a good pointer to how to solve this name resolution issue permanently.

Comment: The above did not work for me, though after adding 127.0.0.1 <hostname> the ping command above worked, where it had timed out before the change to /etc/hosts. I spent some time with the debugger and on Sierra (OS X 10.12) the long timeout is in resolving localhost via ipv6. I'm not able to disable ipv6 so I can't confirm this will resolve the issue. But may be a breadcrumb for someone to follow.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was ipv6 resolution. Damien's answer above was spot on, only needed to add an ipv6 entry to etc/hosts.
Something like:

```
::1        ${your.host.name}
```

Comment: Confirm: only applying both the accepted solution and this one solved my problem. I'm on macOS Sierra, if it does matter.